# Discord.py ModMail system doesnt work without problems

Tags: python, discord, bots, token

When i write !apply the bot write me in my in my private discord messages and ask me questions and when i wrote the answer the bot write the next question but after some questions the bot write 2 questions without waiting on my answer somebody know How to fix it?

The Command Code

```
@bot.command(aliases=['staff-application'])
async def apply(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Send it to you via Private Chat!')
    a_list = []
    submit_channel = bot.get_channel(781551916802113556)
    channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()

    def check(m):
        return m.content is not None and m.channel == channel

    for question in q_list:
        sleep(.30)
        await channel.send(question)
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        a_list.append(msg.content)

    submit_wait = True
    while submit_wait:
        await channel.send('**DAS WÄRE ES** - Schreibe "submit" um die Antworten weiter zu leiten!')
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        if "submit" in msg.content.lower():
            submit_wait = False
            answers = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(a_list, 1))
            submit_msg = f'Application from {msg.author} \nThe answers are:\n{answers}'
            await submit_channel.send(submit_msg)
```

The Question list

```
q_list = [
        'Wie heißt du?',
        'Wie alt bist du?',
        'Wie lautet dein Epic Name?',
        'Als was möchtest du dem Clan beitreten?',
        'Hast du schon Earnings?',
        'Hast du einen Duo Mate?',
        'Warum möchtest du in diesen Clan?',
        'Was willst du hier mal erreichen?'
]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: No i didnt done debugging

Comment: _No i didnt done debugging_ You should start with that, then. I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `await asyncio.sleep()` indtead of `sleep()`.